# Constraint does not work in the cell of my table view

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview

When I add some simple constraint for the cell of my table view, all of labels goes to top left of the cell.

[Image of cell when it is In story board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COA6C.png)

but when I run the application all labels and everything goes to left!!!

[Image of application when it is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW2pQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this button and declare the constraints to a horizontal and vertical positions instead of the pin methods and declare your height and width constraints with it.

[image]

Comment: There is no difference between these two constraints.

Comment: Yes there is a difference one is setting a distance from the edge and the the container the other is setting a distance either horizontally or vertically in the container

Comment: yes, there is difference, I mean for my problem there is no difference.Still  I have this problem.

Comment: What are you trying to constrain the labels too?

Answer (score 0):

To position the labels as you want, you can specify top and left constraints using the "Add new constraints" button in the storyboard:

[image]

You should also specify height and width constraints for the labels:

[image]

Comment: The problem is about cells. When the height of cell get changed from storyboard, then no constraint works. It is about cells inside tableview